# PHP - Session not initializing

Tags: php, forms

I have created a small form for users to fill out after an event. I have my Form.php and the forms action is Mail.php. What it does is, users fill out the form and press submit and the mail.php processes everything.

I'm using a Session to make sure the user can't go back and send me it a second time. Unfortunately, my session won't initiliaze when I publish it online, locally it does.

### Form.php

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['Finished']))
{
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
}
```

### Mail.php

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['INGEVULD']))
{
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
}
else
{ 
    ..(mailing + check)..
    $_SESSION['Finished'] = true;
}
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or have a better suggestion?

Comment: Try dumping your session array, `print_r($_SESSION)` to see what's stored and what not. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Where would you suggest me printing it?

Comment: After `session_start();` on both pages, probably.

Comment: I get Array() on Mail.php and nothing on Form.php

Comment: You should put an exit; behind each header(); line.

Comment: Show the code where you set the session data ... like $_SESSION['Finished'] = ...

Comment: It's as if my Mail.php doesn't reload or load the session.

Comment: Put session_start within a try-catch block to check why the session does not start:
`try {session_start();} catch(Exception $e) {var_dump($e->getMessage();}`

Comment: You call form.php, submit the form to mail.php and then? Back to form.php?

Comment: No, mail.php is it's final destination.

Comment: So in form.php $_SESSION['Finished'] could never be TRUE, because you set it not until mail.php

Comment: $_SESSION['Finished'] is set to TRUE at the end of Mail.php, so this is wrong? Could I assign it to a button_click?

Comment: Do you really need form.php and mail.php? You could do all in one file: Show form, on error show again; on success hide form, send mail, ouput "thank you".

Comment: I have the form.php (showing the form), mail.php (checks the forms + displays errors, sends email, says thank you)

Comment: Yes, you set it in mail.php, but in form.php? This is never set: if(isset($_SESSION['Finished'])), right?

Comment: Correct, but doesn't a session work allover the different pages?

Comment: Yes, it works over all pages, but if you try to access data on page_1, that is set later on page_2, how should page_1 know it before it has been set?

Comment: So Page2 needs to be refreshed in a way? Or after sending the details I should link to a third thank you page? Or perhaps to the Form.php and use a if-else structure with sessiosn?

Comment: Why do you (think you) need $_SESSION['Finished'] in form.php? Do you want to avoid, that it gets send twice? And how about someone wanting to send you 2 e-mails?

Comment: I just want to prevent spamming. If they close the browser they can send it twice :P

Answer (score 0):

You should put an exit; behind each header(); line.

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
exit;
```

Comment: I know, that this is not the answer, but Tom did not get my comment.

Comment: It stops the current script. Otherwise code behind that header line could get run, which you in most cases do not want when doing a header().